# Use returned values of a custom function in loss, based on model predictions

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning

I'm trying to build a model like this in TensorFlow.
The model has "a function" inside the loss function(as A) or before it(as B) which should make an image using the CNN(CNN+Dens layers) estimation of some parameters.
Imagine the input images to be some rectangles with different sizes and coordinations. The neural network supposes to extract these parameters(weight, height, X, and Y of the rectangle). Using these estimated parameters "A function" will recreate the rectangle and send it to a "Distance"(A)/"Loss"(B) function so that the output can be used to update the weights in the neural network.

[image: Model diagram]

I did make every part of the network but when I'm trying to get parameters estimated by CNN for each image to produce an image and send it to loss/distance function, I can't access the real numerical data. instead, the CNN output is a `Tensor`. I tried to eval the `output` using a new `tf.Session` but this happens:

```
FailedPreconditionError: Attempting to use uninitialized value conv2d/kernel
 [[Node: conv2d/kernel/read = Identity[T=DT_FLOAT, _class=["loc:@conv2d/kernel"], _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0"](conv2d/kernel)]]
 [[Node: dense_2/BiasAdd/_11 = _Recv[client_terminated=false, recv_device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0", send_device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0", send_device_incarnation=1, tensor_name="edge_80_dense_2/BiasAdd", tensor_type=DT_FLOAT, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"]()]]
```

**How should I build a model like this in TensorFlow?**

My sample code is like this:
CNN:

```
def cnn_model_fn(features, labels, mode):
   input_layer = tf.reshape(features["x"], [-1, 96,96,1])
   conv1 = tf.layers.conv2d(inputs=input_layer,...)
   other convs....
   output = tf.layers.dense(inputs=lastlayer, units=4)

   predictions = {"params": output}

   if mode == tf.estimator.ModeKeys.PREDICT:
      return   tf.estimator.EstimatorSpec(mode=mode,predictions=predictions)

   # Calculate Loss - here the output will go to "A Function"
   loss = distance_function(features["x"],AFunction(output))

   # Configure the Training Op (for TRAIN mode)
   if mode == tf.estimator.ModeKeys.TRAIN:
       optimizer = ....

   # Add evaluation metrics (for EVAL mode)
   eval_metric_ops = {...}
   return tf.estimator.EstimatorSpec(...)
```

and "A function" is like:

```
def AFunction(y_pred):
   _sess = tf.Session()
   y_pred = _sess.run(y_pred)
   _sess.close()
return rectangle(y_pred)
```

also i tried this and the same error happens:

```
def AFunction(y_pred):
    _sess = tf.Session()
    with _sess.as_default():
        y_pred = y_pred.eval()
return rectangle(y_pred)
```

The distance function is one of the tf.losses functions(should be tested to see which one works best)

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to add the full code here. For a better answer.
From the error, it seems like you need to add tf.global_variables_initializer() before you start doing(Training) anything since some variables are not initialized.
Also it seems you want to create a new loss function based A_Function and images.

```
def A_Function(inp):
    return np.pow(inp,2)/*Do something with input*/
```

In the CNN code write this
`loss = distance_function(features["x"],AFunction(output))`
Now train using

```
with tf.Session as sess:
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
    sess.run(cost, feed_dict) /* Just usual training stuff*/
```